# Partial 301 redirects & SEO strategy

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

This is somewhat of a subjective question. But would like the communities take on this. My client is doing a site split. [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) will turn in to -- [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) + [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com). I know this isn't typically advisable from an SEO perspective, but they are doing it for legal reasons.

Our plan is to only rip out the product pages on [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) and add those on [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com) everything else on domain1 will stay and everything else on domain2 will be original content. So here's the question, still a good idea to do single page 301 redirects for the pages that are transferred?

[www.domain1.com/apples](http://www.domain1.com/apples) > [www.domain2.com/apples](http://www.domain2.com/apples)

I know that's a bit open-ended, without a ton of detail, but if you have specific examples of where you've done something similar, I'd be curious to know what worked/didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a clarification: http 301 is the best for your purpose, because it means permanent redirect (good for SEO, you pass the page and domain authority, link juice...); instead a 302-redirect (http 302) means a temporary redirect, you have no time limits but all the SEO value won't pass! For your purpose, you don't want that.
In general, all pages should be redirected with http 301. Aniyway, with data analysis you can make a decision: if you have a page unuseful, with no traffic, it doesn't need to be redirected, you can use http 404 or http 410 (you can build also a custom 404 page!).
The last thing, must avoid multiple redirects, for example: instead of site1-->site2-->site3 you just need to do: site1-->site3. The reason is each redirect hurts loading speed (also the most common and useful redirect, from http to thhps!!). You just need to avoid multiple ones.